# Is Stream.Write thread-safe?

Tags: c#, multithreading, networking, c#-2.0

I'm working on a client/server library for a legacy RPC implementation and was running into issues where the client would sometimes hang when waiting to a receive a response message to an RPC request message. It turns out the real problem was in my message framing code (I wasn't handling message boundaries correctly when reading data off the underlying `NetworkStream`), but it also made me suspicious of the code I was using to send data across the network, specifically in the case where the RPC server sends a large amount of data to a client as the result of a client RPC request.

My send code uses a `BinaryWriter` to write a complete "message" to the underlying `NetworkStream`. The RPC protocol also implements a heartbeat algorithm, where the RPC server sends out PING messages every 15 seconds. The pings are sent out by a separate thread, so, at least in theory, a ping can be sent while the server is in the middle of streaming a large response back to a client.

Suppose I have a `Send` method as follows, where `stream` is a `NetworkStream`:

```
public void Send(Message message)
{
   //Write the message to a temporary stream so we can send it all-at-once
   MemoryStream tempStream = new MemoryStream();
   message.WriteToStream(tempStream);

   //Write the serialized message to the stream.
   //The BinaryWriter is a little redundant in this 
   //simplified example, but here because
   //the production code uses it.
   byte[] data = tempStream.ToArray();
   BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(stream);
   bw.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
   bw.Flush();
}
```

So the question I have is, is the call to `bw.Write` (and by implication the call to the underlying `Stream`'s `Write` method) atomic? That is, if a lengthy `Write` is still in progress on the sending thread, and the heartbeat thread kicks in and sends a PING message, will that thread block until the original `Write` call finishes, or do I have to add explicit synchronization to the `Send` method to prevent the two `Send` calls from clobbering the stream?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Any public static (Shared in Visual
>   Basic) members of this type are thread
>   safe. Any instance members are not
>   guaranteed to be thread safe.

From [Stream Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx), so **no** it is not guaranteed.

Comment: I saw that as well, but since that disclaimer is applied to almost every single class in the BCL, I wondered if there might be an exception for `Stream` that I might have overlooked elsewhere in the documentation.

Comment: Im sorry, but not that I am aware of. Make sure you take it into your own hands to ensure this section of code is thread safe.

Comment: No need to be sorry ;). I agree that adding explicit synchronization would be the safe and logical thing to do in any event. I was just curious if it was already "built-in" to `Stream`, since the "thread-safe" disclaimer doesn't discount the possibility. MSDN tends to be kind of vague at times.

Answer (score 2):

It is not documented as atomic. I would not assume it is and definitely would wrap that stuff around a custom locking mechanism. Basically the whole Send method pretty much asks for a lock.

Answer (score 0):

You should lock the writer in both threads to be sure. Afair the writer is not thread safe.

Check MSDN for "Monitor" and "Mutex".